# Sort integer array into 4 & 5 times tables C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

I'd like to know the best way to approach this. I have an integer array (say of 3, 4, 8, 10, 15, 24, 29, 30) and I want to sort it into 3 groups: 4 times table, 5 times table, and neither).

As the groups would suggest, it would sort the array into the 4 and 5 times table with another for items that aren't present in either.

What's the best way to approach this in C#? I'm currently using this:

```
          int[] iArray = new int[]{3, 4, 8, 10, 15, 24, 29, 30};

        var iE = iArray.GroupBy ((e) => {
            if (e % 4 == 0) {
                return "four";
            } else if (e % 5 == 0) {
                return "five";
            } else {
                return "other";
            }
        }).OrderBy (e => e.Count ());
```

Produces:

### 4

4
8
24

### 5

10
15
30

### Other

3
29

Comment: Is what you're trying not working?

Comment: You want that in every group data to be sorted ? or just split in groups.

Comment: Your input definitely does not produce that output - furthermore, your approach simply won't work, 6 is divisible by both 2 and 3, it shouldn't be constrained to be in a single group, but your code short circuits at the first condition.

Comment: Jacob, it works fine as is, was curious if anybody had any alternative approaches.

George Lica, split into groups.

Preston Guillot, yes sorry I was using another data set, updated my example.

user2946329, another nice solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
```

If you want to get *all* multiples of 4 and *all* multiples of 5 (and have some overlap between the two) you can do this:

```
List<int> multiplesOf4 = (from i in arr where i % 4 == 0 select i).ToList();
List<int> multiplesOf5 = (from i in arr where i % 5 == 0 select i).ToList();
List<int> others = (from i in arr where i % 5 != 0 && i % 4 != 0 select i).ToList();
```

If you want no overlap, however, you need to pick which one will be dominant. I chose 4 here:

```
List<int> multiplesOf4 = new List<int>(),
          multiplesOf5 = new List<int>(),
          others       = new List<int>();
foreach (int i in arr)
{
    if (i % 4 == 0)
        multiplesOf4.Add(i);
    else if (i % 5 == 0)
        multiplesOf5.Add(i);
    else
        others.Add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var numberGroupsTimes5 =
            from n in numbers
            group n by n % 5 into g
            where g.Key == 0
            select new { Remainder = g.Key, Numbers = g };

var numberGroupsTimes4 =
            from n in numbers
            group n by n % 4 into g
            where g.Key == 0
            select new { Remainder = g.Key, Numbers = g };

foreach (var g in numberGroupsTimes5)
{
     string st = string.Format("Numbers with a remainder of {0} when divided by 5:" , g.Remainder);
     MessageBox.Show("" + st);
     foreach (var n in g.Numbers)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(""+n);
     }
} 
foreach (var g in numberGroupsTimes4)
{
     string st = string.Format("Numbers with a remainder of {0} when divided by 4:", g.Remainder);
     MessageBox.Show("" + st);
     foreach (var n in g.Numbers)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("" + n);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You approach is correct. But you can do some small improvements to make it more readable and standard:

```
var iArray = new[] { 3, 4, 8, 10, 15, 24, 29, 30 };//Don't need to give type(int) explicitly
var iE = iArray.GroupBy(e => e % 4 == 0 ? "four" : e % 5 == 0 ? "five" : "other").OrderBy(e => e.Count());
```

It'll give the same results.